# Fake ssl cetificate for development

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl

I am using asp.net 3.5 with c#, I want to develop website with SSL transaction. But before Developing the site I want to work with SSL to learn more from it.
Please let me know from where I can get the dummy SSL or Fake SSL so that I could do the development work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

makecert can be used,

Client certificate
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650751.aspx

Server certificate
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751408.aspx